# PHP to MYSQL datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I have this kind of date format on my datetimepicker:

```
16 September 2015 - 08:25 am
```

but i want to store something like this:

```
2015-09-16 08:25:00
```

on my database

how will i be able to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: jquery date picker? it has an alt format just for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a weird date format that is not directly supported by strtotime(). However, just removing the dash fixes it:

```
var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace("-", "", "16 September 2015 - 08:25 am"))));
# outputs: string(19) "2015-09-16 08:25:00"
```

This does however look a bit hacky so please consider using a different date format in your picker as other commenters suggested.

Comment: Thank you, i have used this, but i will change my datepicker to change the format. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this before inserting to database:

`$new_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime(str_replace("-","",$your_date)));`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do something like parsing your date using [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), then use [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to output it in your desired new format.

Comment: Yes, i agree, thank you, though i have to change the date format of my datetime picker...thank you.